# XQuery multivalued fields (IDREFS)

Tags: xml, xquery

In my XML file I have this element

```
 <subtopics>tr1 tr2</subtopics>
```

which I retrieve in XQuery using the following query

```
doc("data.xml")/expert_schema/topic/data(subtopics)
```

How can I retrive `tr1`and `tr2`separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is not a problem, then you can simply tokenize the values as you query them:

```
doc("data.xml")/expert_schema/topic/tokenize(subtopics, '\s')
```

Comment: Note also that if you use a schema-aware query, and subtopics is typed as xs:IDREF, then data(subtopics) will do the tokenization for you, returning a sequence of two strings.